# Derivation and ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is came from Exercise 25.3 of Matsumura. Let $A$ be a ring, $I$ be an ideal, $D \in \operatorname{Der}(A,A)$. For $n>0$, why $D(I^{n}) \subset I^{n-1}$ holds? To see this, it suffices to show that for any $a \in I \setminus I^{2}$, $D(a) \in A \setminus I$. However, I don't know why $D(a) \not\in I$. Also there is not much conditions I can use. Could you give any hint for this problem?

Comment: Isn't $D(I^{n}) \subset I^{n-1}$ immediate from additivity and the Leibniz rule? After all, elements of $I^{n}$ are sums of products of the form $x_{1}x_{2} \cdots x_{n}$ where $x_{i} \in I$, so it's enough to show that $D(x_{1}x_{2}\cdots x_{n})$ belongs to $I^{n-1}$ for $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \in I$. Now use Leibniz...

Comment: You do not need to show that $D(a)\notin I$, which is good, because it's frequently false (think about the zero derivation, for instance, or $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ acting on $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$). Alex Wertheim's comment should put you on the right path.

Comment: @AlexWertheim and KReiser Thank you very much! I wrongly think that I need to show $D(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)$ is only in $I^{n-1}$ not $I^{n}$.